# Сортировать кортежи в списке сначала по большим буквам, потом по маленьким, затем Bool ицифрами

Tags: списки, haskell

function = [(a,b,c,d)| a <- [0,50,100,150,200], b <- ['a', 'b', 'c'], c <- [True, False], d <-['A','B']]

Создала функцию, создающую разные кортежи, только как вот их посортировать сначала по значению d, потом по b, потом по c и наконец а..?
Может кто-нибудь может помочь, буду очень благодарна.

Пыталась встроить sortBy...но чего-то не получается...

Comment: sortBy (compare `on` (\(a,b,c,d) -> (d,b,c,a)))

Comment: Почему не как ответ?

Answer (score 0):

**Перенесено из коментария.**

Искомое выражение:

```
sortBy (compare on ((a,b,c,d) -> (d,b,c,a)))
```